# How to check file/directory changes of a multi directory git repository between two git commits?

Tags: bash, git

How to check file/directory changes of a multi directory git repository between two git commits?

In linux/bash we need to findout changes to a directory of multi-directory(e-store) git repository, say it has inventory-dir, order-dir, purchase-dir etc.., directories.

So basically after we do `git pull` we want to know in which folderes/directories files changes were made between present changes & last commit, and based on that output take an appropriate call.

We tried to use below git commands, but not sure that's the right way to proceed.

```
git diff inventory-dir

git log --name-status -2 inventory-dir
```

Comment: Have you tried `git diff --name-only SHA1 SHA2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for

```
git diff @^1
```

but to reduce the result to a tractable list of just file names you could add

```
--stat
```

or

```
--compact-summary
```

or merely

```
--name-only
```

Of those, my favorite is `--compact-summary` — it's tremendously informative while confining the output to one line per file. So then if you have a top-level directory *myDirectory* to which you wish to confine your attention, you would say

```
git diff --compact-summary @^1 -- myDirectory
```